# Error SSRS processing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I have a SSRS reporting connected to a SSAS cube. When I run the report in Visual Studio I get the error:

> Exception of type
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException
>   was thrown

But If I run the query from SSMS it works fine.
What could be the issue?

Comment: Check your SSRS error logs for a more specific error message.

Comment: Where can I find the logs for SSDT?

Comment: Depends on your version, and how the service was configured.   This should help:   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=where+to+find+SSRS+error+logs&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=where+to+find+SSRS+error+logs&gs_l=hp...0i22i30.0.0.0.6089...........0.h4rCcFBZHwo